# My regex to find a pattern in an img src attribut fails when the searched pattern starts with a t

Tags: javascript, html, regex, href, src

I built a regex to find any href or src attribute value in a html string that does not start with 'http'.

My solution seems to work in most cases, except when the attribute value starts with a 't'. I don't understand why. Can someone explain why this happens?

examples (in javascript):

```
//this gives the expected match
'<img href="somename.jpg">'.match(/(?:href|src)\=\"([^(http)][^(\")]*)\"/);

//this does NOT give the expected match
'<img href="thisname.jpg">'.match(/(?:href|src)\=\"([^(http)][^(\")]*)\"/);
```

Here is the regex I am using:

```
/(?:href|src)\=\"([^(http)][^(\")]*)\"/
```

Comment: And you didn't post the regex? Fine, answer is: Because your regex is wrong :D

Comment: @DanteTheSmith the regex is right there `/(?:href|src)\=\"([^(http)][^(\")]*)\"/`

Comment: @Jan van Casteren why not use a positive match instead? You could get a word of any length by replacing `[^(http)]` with `(\w{0,})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^(http)]` here is your problem you basically said not h not t and not p with this.

I am willing to assume you thought of (?!http) as a negative look-ahead group to eliminate all http literals from the URL.

This should suffice (short n simple)

```
(?:href|src)="(?!http:\/\/).*\"
```

In case you are only trying to eliminate ones starting with http and not actually check if something is a valid URL afterwards

Comment: Although other answers were helpful too, I choose this one because it answers my question and it gives an example that point me in the right direction, my final solution is /(?:href|src)="(?!https?:\/\/).*"/  (it includes https and leaves out the unnecessary escaping of the last double quote)

Comment: or better /(?:href|src)="(?!https?:\/\/)([^"]+)"/ because it extracts the attribute value as the second capture group.

Comment: I am glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 2):

It might be, that `[^(http)]` excludes all occurences of  h, t and p.
Try, if "psomename.jpg" does not work, too.

Comment: You're right, that pattern excludes anything that includes the characters `(`, `h`, `t`, `p`, and `)`. You can't group together multiple characters in a character class: https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a lookahead assertion:

```
/(?:href|src)="(?!https?:\/\/)[^"]+"/
```

This is a negative lookahead. In this situation, it matches your string if it is not preceded by `http://` (or also `https://`). A simpler example of it is `(?!a)b` which is `b` not preceded by `a`. A negative lookbehind would also work `(?<!string)` but I don't think it's supported in JavaScript.

https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img href="thisname.jpg">'.match(/(?:href|src)\=\"([^(http)]?[^(\")]*)\"/);
```